# How to install recent packages?

Tags: r, plotly, devtools

I'm trying to install the more recent packages `devtools` and `plotly`, but I can't download recent packages. For example, the more recent version of `devtools` is `1.12.0` and for `plotly` is `4.5.5.9000`. How to install these recent packages?

```
session_info()
Session info ---------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.2.4 (2016-03-16)
 system   x86_64, mingw32             
 ui       RStudio (0.99.896)          
 language (EN)                        
 collate  Portuguese_Brazil.1252      
 tz       America/Sao_Paulo           
 date     2016-11-15                  

Packages -------------------------------------------------------------------
 package       * version date       source        
 devtools      * 1.10.0  2016-01-23 CRAN (R 3.2.4)
 digest          0.6.9   2016-01-08 CRAN (R 3.2.4)
 memoise         0.2.1   2014-04-22 CRAN (R 3.2.0)
 RevoUtilsMath * 3.2.4   2016-04-20 local
```

Comment: I guess maybe your mirror takes their time in adding the newer versions. Try this `repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org'` in your install.packages statement

Comment: You could directly download from  https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=devtools

Comment: btw some more information about what you tried would be useful :)

Comment: It works! Tank you guys!

Comment: I installed, but still show error.

`* installing *source* package 'plotly' ...
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** tests
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error : object 'as_tibble' is not exported by 'namespace:tibble'
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'plotly'
* removing 'C:/Users/Wagner/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/plotly'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/Wagner/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/plotly' `

Comment: @d.b Sure, done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your mirror takes their time in adding the newer versions. Try this

`repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org'` in your install.packages statement

Comment: As a side note, `repos` works with `update.packages()` too